# Fuzzy string matching with group_by

Tags: r, group-by, fuzzy, fuzzy-comparison

I have to identify payments that are not always transferred with the same combination of NAME - IBAN.

Let's say I have a table called "payments" that looks like this:

```
IBAN       NAME
ABCD       James Dito
ABCD       James D.
ABCD       J Dito
ABCD       Peter Oliver
EDFG       Ana Pirez
EDFG       ANA P.
```

What I would like to identify is that the iban "ABCD" corresponds normally to James Dito (or its fuzzy match) but one payment was transfer to the iban "ABCD" with a complete different name: Peter Oliver.

My idea is to do a `group_by` with fuzzy matching within each IBAN group, but I don't know how to do that.

Thus, the ideal output should look like this:

```
IBAN       NAME
ABCD       James Dito
ABCD       Peter Oliver
EDFG       Ana Pirez
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try the `stringdist` package. It has various methods for measuring distance between strings. You can probably use it to create a custom function for your requirements